# Как инициализировать UIAlertController с кастомным вью?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit

Есть view с какими-то элементами, есть новый UIAlertController (от которого нельзя наследоваться), но можно добавить к вью алерта саб вью, собственно мой кастомный вью. Добавить можно, но все элементы некликабельные. Можно ли как то к ним достучаться? Есть ли решения для кастомизации алертов таким методом?

Comment: покажите что и как вы добавляете

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko https://gist.github.com/dotprox/6943e89334e236e7fc3aa8c0e2a8f779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если задать алерту достаточный размер (например вписать в title \n\n\n\n\n), то поля на вью становятся кликабельными

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let alertView: UIView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("View", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
alertView.frame = CGRectMake(alert.view.bounds.minX, alert.view.bounds.minY, alert.view.frame.width/2, alert.view.frame.height/2)
alertView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
alert.view.addSubview(alertView)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
alert.addAction(action)
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: https://cocoapods.org/pods/CustomIOSAlertView нашел лучшее решение для себя